# Unity Android and iOS handle textures at runtime

Tags: c#, android, ios, unity-game-engine, textures

I am developing an mobile application for Android an iOS with Unity to display panoramic images.

The images are downloaded and saved in the local storage of the device. One image is about 5mb to 10mb.

I am using [WWW.LoadImageIntoTexture](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.LoadImageIntoTexture.html) at start of the app. But if I have more than seven images the app crashes. I figured out that LoadImageToTexture creates images with RGBA32 format. So each texture has about 100mb. So the crash is caused by full memory.

I tried Texture2d.Compress() but it only compresses to DXT1 or DTX5. Android can not handle DXT format.

New idea is to preload the image I want to view next. (Only one image is visible)
I tried to load the texture with a Coroutine. But the app stucks while using WWW.LoadImageIntoTexture about one second. So I tried threading. But WWW.LoadImageIntoTexture can not be executed outside the unity-main-thread.

Is there a way to execute WWW.LoadImageIntoTexture asynchronous? I tried with UniRX from the AssetStore:

```
public void StartPreloadPanorama(string targetid){
    preloadFinished = false;
    StartCoroutine (PreloadHandler ());
}

IEnumerator PreloadHandler(){
    var preload = Observable.FromCoroutine(PreloadPanorama)
        .Subscribe();

    while (!preloadFinished) {
        yield return null;
    }
}

IEnumerator PreloadPanorama(){
    //texture is a public string
    WWW preloadTexturer = new WWW("file://"+texture);
    Texture2D texTemp = new Texture2D (8192, 4096, TextureFormat.RGBA32, true);
    preloadTexturer.LoadImageIntoTexture(texTemp);
    preloadFinished = true;

    //edit - there is some more code after that:

    //preloadRenderer is a public Renderer attached to the gameobject displaying the panorama image
    preloadRenderer.material.mainTexture = texTemp;

    Resources.UnloadUnusedAssets();
    Debug.Log("FINISHED");
    yield return null;
}
```

But I still get the stucking...

Any ideas? Thanks!

Edit: according to the comments here is my setup:

I have two spheres, one active, one disabled. (GameObject.SetActive(false))
My camera is inside the spheres. Camera and the two spheres have the position 0,0,0 - you can move the camera by gyro. 
There are some buttons placed inside the spheres. If you gaze at a button for 2 seconds the active sphere is disabled and the other sphere is activated. By starting the gaze the StartPreloadPanorama() function is called and a new picture is attached to the disabled sphere.

Comment: What format is the image you are downloading? When you say that the size is `510mb`? Are you sure about this? How do you know that?

Comment: It's jpg - but the size is not 510mb it is 5mb to 10mb. The smallest images are about 5mb and the biggest ones about 10mb.

Comment: Ok. I was confused about the size. Good thing you edited the question. It crashes when you load how many image?

Comment: 7 images works. When loading 8 images the app crashes and Android monitor says: "Could not allocate memory: System out of memory!"

Comment: Your `PreloadPanorama` function is not complete. It shouldn't be able to compile. Please post what it looks like. Also, show us how you are dispalying this on the screen. I think I know what the problem is but I want to be 100% sure before posting solution. It would also be good to describe what exactly you are doing with those images. For example, click to show next image.....Maybe there is a better way of that.

Comment: I added the missing code. The function StartPreloadPanorama is triggered by a event listener. "OnPointerEnter"

Comment: Ok. How about the rest of my questions like what you are doing...I want to know if this needs Object pooling.

Comment: I don't think object pooling is doing the trick because I have different content in my GameObjects. The problem is the memory by loading all images at start resp. the lack by using the CPU-intensive function WWW.LoadImageIntoTexture() dynamically...